No such key error ListObjectsV2Command AWS S3
I need to get the list of the logs that are stored on AWS S3 (spases object storage digital ocean), path is correct, and file listing is enabled, but I am getting such error: Error listing files: NoSuchKey: UnknownError
library: @aws-sdk/client-s3
Here is my code:
      const listParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.DO_BUCKET,
        Prefix: '2021-09-01/'
      };

      const files = await this.s3Client.send(
        new ListObjectsV2Command(listParams),
      );

I was trying different formats of path, different buckets but still not working. Also interesting that other comands like GetObjectCommand works well

Does it work if you use the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI) command aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/2021-09-01/?
